# Finished cooking or just cooked?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which of these sentences sounds more natural?

> 1- We just cooked fish
>
> 2 - We just finished cooking fish

Usually I would use **"We just made fish"**, but I want to use the verb *cook*.  Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most natural to me (British English) would be either

> We've just cooked some fish.

or

> We've just finished cooking some fish.

The only difference between them is that the second has emphasised the "finish" - that might imply that cooking the fish was a lengthy process, or perhaps that we have washed up the pans we were using.

I would not use "We just cooked" or "We just finished cooking", but I think that American speakers would do so.

And leaving out "some" is grammatical, but not natural, to my ear. I tend to use "fish" without a determiner when it has a general sense, (eg *I often cook fish*) but not when it refers to some particular fish.

And yes, I **am** saying that there is nothing to choose between your sentences, for naturalness.